# Genymotion Interface Incompatibility

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm quite new to Mobile App development. Today I downloaded the Android Studio and Genymotion, and I simply designed a layout, ran it and saw that the interface gets messed up, the objects are not where they are suppossed to be. Check this out for instance. There are two buttons however in the emulator all messed up.

[image]

I already tried to change the version to 6.0.0 or to others, did not work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess its not an issue with genymotion , may be with your xml. Can you paste your xml here?

Comment: If it was the xml, it would have looked messed up in the studio itself. However, it looks fine in there, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: No, the problem **is** the XML, because you used `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using constraint layout? If yes please correct all of its error inside your xml. Because it clearly gives warning to you that **`if you do not correct constraints it will jump to 0 positions`**. This might be the main reason behind the control jump to 0 position